# Error de Mapeo Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

tengo el siguiente fichero xml de Hibernate:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ProgramacionAvanzada2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">postgres</property>
    <mapping class="MODELO.CalendarioReservas" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Cliente" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.DatosPersonales" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Empleado" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Factura" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Habitacion" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Hotel" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Mesa" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Pedido" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Plato" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Proveedor" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Renglon" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.ReservaHabitacion" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.ReservaMesa" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Servicio" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Tarjeta" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.Usuario" package="MODELO"/>
    <mapping class="MODELO.TarjetaCredito" package="MODELO"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Esta es la función que intenta persistir un nuevo objeto:

```
public void guardar(Object objeto) {
        // Abrir una sesion (conexion a la DB)
        Session sesion = miFabricaSesion.openSession();

        // Iniciar una transaccion
        sesion.getTransaction().begin();

        // Agregar un objeto a la DB
        sesion.persist(objeto);

        // Guardar los cambios
        sesion.getTransaction().commit();

        sesion.close();
    }
```

Al dar run, me sale esto:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: MODELO.TarjetaCredito
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1095)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1448)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785)
    at CONTROLADOR.ControladorPersistencia.guardar(ControladorPersistencia.java:52)
```

Sin embargo, como se ve mas arriba, si tengo mapeado mi clase "TarjetaCredito". Ver:

```
<mapping class="MODELO.TarjetaCredito" package="MODELO"/>
```

**Alguien me ayudaría a resolver este error? Gracias de antemano.**

Comment: Dentro de la clase "miFabricaSesion" ¿tienes ya configurado el llamado al XML de Hibernate donde tienes la configuración?

Comment: Si lo tengo configurado:
        miFabricaSesion = new Configuration().configure(".\\PERSISTENCIA\\hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

Comment: Puedes incluir el código relativo a miFabricaSesion y también la clase TarjetaCredito por favor?